# Return Variable From Method

Tags: c#, variables, return-value

I know how to pass variables to a procedure, but how do I return a variable to the calling procedure?  For example, this is my syntax, no issue at all passing in the variable `arr` but how can I return the value `nummmm` back to `Main`?  Please disregard the empty sqlconnection & update statement etc, they are valid in my actual syntax.

```
namespace ConsoleTest
{
  class Test
  {
    public static string SQLConnectionString = "";
    public static string updatestatement = null;
    public static string[] arrArray;
    public int 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        arrArray = new string[3] { "1412", "1618", "1223" };
        foreach (string arr in arrArray)
        {
          runupdates(arr, out nummmm);
        }
    }

    private static int runupdates(string arr, out int nummmm)
    {
        updatestatement = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updatestatement, connection))
            {
            command.CommandText = updatestatement;
            int nummmm = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My edited code now give a compile error of 'Not All Code Paths return a value.

Comment: @Shaharyar this is a C# example, I have never used 'out'

Comment: do you know what the key word `void` means..? and if you've never used `out` then google it come on now.. void means the method or procedure has no return / does not return.. however you can still trick it by using the `out` key word.. better start reading and understanding the basics because if someone gave you the proper method signature how would you understand it anyway

Comment: You need to learn the basics of C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84

Comment: @MethodMan - I am googling now to learn how to use this.  And yes I know what void means, if out is the method I use, it can not have a void return type.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question by the title. You can simply return the value from a method. as **SLaks** suggested.

Comment: Proper turn for C# is "method" - so https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+return+value+method

Comment: You don't need "using" for the command object, just the using for Connection, and you don't have to close it either, the using statement will handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function itself to return the value.  You do not need an additional output parameter.

```
private static int runupdates(string arr)
{
    updatestatement = "";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updatestatement, connection))
        {
        command.CommandText = updatestatement;
        int nummmm = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        }
    }
    return nummmm;
}
```

Comment: That's returning a *value*, not a *variable*.  Big difference.

Comment: @Servy OP doesn't even know about returning a value, may be he is asking the same but doesn't know how to ask

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a value from a method, you must indicate it. The type "void" means that your method it's not gonna to return a value. In your case, if you want to return an int, change the type "void" for "int" and add a return sentence